Finding a Fixed Point for nested Squareroots
I am trying to prove, with the help of the banach fixed-point theorem, that there exists a limit, or in other words, a fixed point of this term:
$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\underbrace{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{3+\dots+2\sqrt{3}}}}}_{k \ Squareroots}$
I am using the function $\phi:\mathbb{R_+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}, \phi(x)=\sqrt{3+2x}$ with a suitable starting point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R_+}$.
To use the Banach Fixed-point theorem however i want to show that the function $\phi(x)$ is indeed a contracting mapping, i.e there exists a $k \in (0,1)$ so that
$\lVert\phi(x)-\phi(y)\rVert \leq k\lVert x-y \rVert, \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R_+}$.
My idea now was to use the Mean-Value-Theorem
to deduce out of the fact that $\phi'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3+2x}}$ and therefore $\phi'(x)<1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R_+}$ there definetly exists a $k \in (0,1)$ so that $\phi$ is a contracting mapping and the Banach Fixed-Point theorem is applicable.
Would this work?

Is it intentional that in the first square root the factor 2 is missing?

With square roots you can use the binomial theorem
$$
|\sqrt{3+2y}-\sqrt{3+2x}|=\frac{2|y-x|}{\sqrt{3+2y}+\sqrt{3+2x}}
\le \frac{|y-x|}{\sqrt3}.
$$
This is sufficient for the fixed-point theorem.

You can get this result also more elementary, as the sequence is increasing, with increasing index/square root count only positive terms get added, and it is bounded, for instance by 5.

This works with a little bit more caution:
$\phi'(x)<1$ is not sufficient, but we need more strongly $\phi'(x)\le k$ where $k$ is a constant that is strictly less than $1$. Surely this is easy in this particular case, as $\phi'(x)\le \phi'(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<1$.
Wikipedia contains a good example otherwise:
$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ has no fixed point over $[1, \infty)$, despite $f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2}<1$ for all $x\ge 1$.
